# What is the best way to migrate a MVC 2 project to MVC 3 using the Razor view engine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

What is the best way to migrate a MVC 2 project to MVC 3 using the Razor view engine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Details can be found in [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx) from ScottGu's blog (see the **How to Upgrade Existing Projects** section).  I used the [MVC 3 project upgrade tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx) and had only a few minor issues specific to my application after running it.

Answer (score 3):

There are also links to upgrade tools on David Hayden's blog: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/05/ASPNETMVC3TutorialsIndex.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Telerik wrote a program to convert usual aspx views to razor

Have a look here : https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter

Answer (score 2):

Do you need/want to move to Razor or just having MVC 3? You can still use your aspx pages with the WebFormViewEngine and MVC 3.
This what I did on my side because we had quite a big app and more than just a few issues when migrating to MVC 3. So for a while we kept apsx pages and moved pages progressively to cshtml.

Answer (score -1):

There is no substitute for learning the Razor Syntax

[Programming Razor](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449312824)

I think that some developers over-think razor and make it harder than it is.  If you know HTML, JavaScript and C#, just learn some of the basic syntax like a code block

```
@model MyApp.Models.MyEntity

@{
    // this is a code block
    ViewBag.MyData = "i need to use a semicolon here";
}

<div class="myclass">
//This is inline razor/C# code that uses a 
//lambda expression to access a model property:
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyProperty)
</div>
```

The razor engine knows where the C# ends and the HTML begins, you just need to learn a few basic rules.

Edit: The point I am trying to make is that tools are not the only way to convert from MVC 2 to MVC 3 or 4 Razor. Conversion tools are not perfect.  Knowledge of the Razor syntax can also be very helpful.

Comment: Ok so what is your point?  You dont have to know the razor syntax to convert from MVC2 to MVC3?  I dont think that upgrade tools are the only way to convert from MVC2 to MVC3.  Sometimes manual conversion of ASPX to Razor is necessary so knowing the razor syntax is always a good idea.