# How to create ASP .NET Application from existing files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I wanted to download this sample http://mvctimeplanner.codeplex.com/
The author did not attach solution file only the project(all source files inside the project folder).

[image]

How to create solution from those files?

### EDIT

Also it is ASP .NET MVC 2 project, and the oldest I got is ASP .NET MVC 4 and I use ASP .NET MVC 5.1 so running failed.

Is there a similar demo which I can just download and run to see how it works? I looked for a while month ago and now and I cannot find one.

Comment: open VS and go to file > open as a website.

Comment: @Yoda Thank you it worked. Could you please have a look edit of my original post at the bottom of it? I know it is little offtopic, but I just look for sample solution to run and see how it works.

Comment: I've written my comment above as a answer, if it worked for you, please accept the answer. If you don't find solution of the other question then open that as a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open that folder as a website by going to File > Open > Website in Visual Studio

For your other question, you should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4960196/1211329).